# Html zoom only div element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I have angular project and I want to zoom some div on scroll.

So far I only found zoomooz.js library which is based on jquery. So I want to know if there is any other library which is not based on jquery but on angukarjs. Or if anyone know how to scroll only one div as simple as posible.

Comment: `theDiv.scrollTop = y;`?

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: The comment is an example ; ). You've to elaborate your question before a real use case could be created. I doubt you actually don't want to zoom a div on scroll, rather you'd want to zoom a div when user uses mousewheel, and prevent the rest of the page to scroll, right?

Comment: right. I want to zoom only one div like this do ctrl + mousewheel for entire page.

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utoqpmc4/) is near the simplest solution, works at least in newest Chrome, FF and IE. Or a slightly [different version](http://jsfiddle.net/utoqpmc4/1/).